# Pandas Python writing to existing file and matching column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 excel sheets that I have loaded.  I need to add information from one to the other one.  See example below.

```
table 1:
cust_id    fname    lname   date_registered
1          bob      holly   1/1/80
2          terri    jones   2/3/90

table 2:
fname    lname    date_registered   cust_id   zip
lawrence fisher   2/3/12            3         12345
```

So I need to add cust_id 3 from table 2 to table 1.  Along with all the other information, fname, lname, and date_registered.  I don't need all the columns though, such as the zip.

I am thinking I can use the pandas/merge.  But I am new to all this and not sure how this works.  I need to populate the next row in table 1 with the corresponding row information in table 2. Any information would be helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: looks to me like you need to concat not merge. You are just adding rows from table2 to table 1 no?

Answer (score 1):

With concat:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: table_1 = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id':[1,2], 'fname':['bob', 'teri'], 'lname':['holly', 'jones'], 'date_registered':['1/1/80', '2/3/90']})

In [3]: table_2 = pd.DataFrame({'cust_id':[3], 'fname':['lawrence'], 'lname':['fisher'], 'date_registered':['2/3/12'], 'zip':[12345]})

In [4]: final_table = pd.concat([table_1, table_2])

In [5]: final_table
Out[5]: 
   cust_id date_registered     fname   lname      zip
0        1          1/1/80       bob   holly      NaN
1        2          2/3/90      teri   jones      NaN
0        3          2/3/12  lawrence  fisher  12345.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [append](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
appended = table1.append(table2[table1.columns])
```

or [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
concated = pd.concat([table1,table2], join='inner')
```

Both resulting in

```
    cust_id fname       lname   date_registered
0   1       bob         holly   1/1/80
1   2       terri       jones   2/3/90
0   3       lawrence    fisher  2/3/12
```